# Jupyter notebook parou de funcionar

Tags: python

Estava usando o jupyer notebook há horas e do nada ele começou a dar erro em todas as células. Quando fui rodar tudo desde o começo ele deu erro em TUDO. O que pode ter acontecido? O que eu faço?

```
import numpy as np

numpy.version.full_version

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

< ipython-input-2-62e0f0393730> in <module>

      1 import numpy as np

----> 2 numpy.version.full_version

NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

No meu prompt de comando recebo uma notificação assim:

```
c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be
 deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
```

Comment: Você fez `import numpy as np` então ao se referir ao *numpy* use `np`.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, veja que vc primeiro importou o numpy e criou uma alias **np**

```
import numpy as np
```

na linha seguinte deveria usar esta alias

```
np.version.full_version
```